# Filter out rows with more than certain number of NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

In a Pandas dataframe, I would like to filter out all the rows that have more than 2 `NaN`s.

Essentially, I have 4 columns and I would like to keep only those rows where at least 2 columns have finite values.

Can somebody advise on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following should work

```
df.dropna(thresh=2)
```

See the [online docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)

What we are doing here is dropping any `NaN` rows, where there are 2 or more non `NaN` values in a row.

Example:

```
In [25]:

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,NaN,4,5], 'b':[NaN,2,NaN,4,5], 'c':[1,2,NaN,NaN,NaN], 'd':[1,2,3,NaN,5]})

df

Out[25]:

    a   b   c   d
0   1 NaN   1   1
1   2   2   2   2
2 NaN NaN NaN   3
3   4   4 NaN NaN
4   5   5 NaN   5

[5 rows x 4 columns]

In [26]:

df.dropna(thresh=2)

Out[26]:

   a   b   c   d
0  1 NaN   1   1
1  2   2   2   2
3  4   4 NaN NaN
4  5   5 NaN   5

[4 rows x 4 columns]
```

**EDIT**

For the above example it works but you should note that you would have to know the number of columns and set the `thresh` value appropriately, I thought originally it meant the number of `NaN` values but it actually means number of ***Non*** `NaN` values.

Comment: What If I wanted to create a dataframe of those rows that have 2 or more null values, not drop them. How do I do that?

Comment: Use: df = df[df.isnull().sum(axis=1) >= 2]

Answer (score 16):

You have phrased 2 slightly different questions here. In the *general* case, they have different answers.

> I would like to keep only those rows where at least 2 columns have
>   finite values.

```
df = df.dropna(thresh=2)
```

This **keeps** rows with 2 or more **non-null values**.

---

> I would like to filter out all the rows that have more than 2 `NaNs`

```
df = df.dropna(thresh=df.shape[1]-2)
```

This **filters out** rows with 2 or more **null values**.

In your example dataframe of 4 columns, these operations are equivalent, since `df.shape[1] - 2 == 2`. However, you will notice discrepancies with dataframes which do not have exactly 4 columns.

---

Note `dropna` also has a `subset` argument should you wish to include only specified columns when applying a threshold. For example:

```
df = df.dropna(subset=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], thresh=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a slightly different problem i.e. to filter out **columns** with more than certain number of NaN:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,np.nan,4,5], 'b':[np.nan,2,np.nan,4,5], 'c':[1,2,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan], 'd':[1,2,3,np.nan,5]})
df

    a   b   c   d
0   1.0 NaN 1.0 1.0
1   2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0
2   NaN NaN NaN 3.0
3   4.0 4.0 NaN NaN
4   5.0 5.0 NaN 5.0
```

Assume you want to filter out columns with 3 or more Nan's:

```
num_rows = df.shape[0]
drop_cols_with_this_amount_of_nans_or_more = 3
keep_cols_with_at_least_this_number_of_non_nans = num_rows - drop_cols_with_this_amount_of_nans_or_more + 1

df.dropna(axis=1,thresh=keep_cols_with_at_least_this_number_of_non_nans)
```

output: (column c has been dropped as expected):

```
    a   b   d
0   1.0 NaN 1.0
1   2.0 2.0 2.0
2   NaN NaN 3.0
3   4.0 4.0 NaN
4   5.0 5.0 5.0
```